# Auto URL Rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am very newbie in **mod-rewrite** with **.htaccess** and i need some help to make this working.

For example, i have these two urls:

- www.example.com/categories/example1
- www.example.com/categories/example2

And i want to auto rewrite it as:

- www.example.com/mypage/?cat=example1
- www.example.com/mypage/?cat=example2

Any way to rewrite this with .htaccess?

I already tried this but still not working...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^example1([^/]*)$ mypage/?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /mypage/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^\&]*)
RewriteRule ^mypage/$ categories/%1.php? [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the "`example1`" bit to be "`categories`" and you don't want to redirect to end with ".php". So something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^categories/([^/]*)$ mypage/?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /mypage/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cat=([^\&]*)
RewriteRule ^mypage/$ categories/%1? [R,L]
```

Comment: It's not working. It's because i'm using wordpress and i must add anything else on code?

Comment: @JohnSmith if you're using wordpress, then use wordpress's built in rewriting for permalinks

Comment: But i can't do it using .htaccess?

Comment: @JohnSmith not for permalinks, no